# Get selected option from Menu Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I need to get selected folder number from Menu to manipulate such data next time. Tried to implement optionMenu to make program easier, but I need to create Frame, which contains several Menus.

Using callback(menu) method I tried to get the number, however program prints first two numbers.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x150")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

menu_frame = Menu(root)
file_menu = Menu(menu_frame, tearoff=0)

folders = ['25', '70', '200']

sub_menu = Menu(menu_frame, tearoff=0)
for folder in folders:
     sub_menu.add_command(label=folder, command=lambda: callback(sub_menu))

file_menu.add_cascade(label='Open folder... ', menu=sub_menu)
menu_frame.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=root.destroy)

def callback(menu):
    for index in range(2):
        x = menu.entrycget(index, "label")
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to add `folder` as an argument to `callback()`, which you can pass in via the `lambda`

```
sub_menu = Menu(menu_frame, tearoff=0)
for folder in folders:
     sub_menu.add_command(label=folder, command=lambda f=folder: callback(f))


def callback(folder):
    print(folder)
```